# Query String on Web API not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api controller that has two actions, but only one of them can receive requests.

```
public class ApiBase : ApiController
{
}

[RoutePrefix("api/Test")]
public class TestController : ApiBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {} // I only want this action to handle http://blah/api/Test but it's also handling http://blah/api/Test?id=1

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] int id){} // http://blah/api/Test?id=1 couldn't reach here
}
```

I realized the problem is with base class. If `TestController` doesn't inherit from base class, it works as expected. What's missing from my base class?

Comment: Having the placeholder in the route means it will map to `api/Test/1`

Comment: @Nkosi, thanks. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attribute routing definition has a routing pattern `api/Test/{id}` mapped to the second Get method. So you should be accessing it like `/api/test/34`

When using attribute routing , the default routing with the querystrings and `?` won't work. You should use the pattern defined in the attribute route definition.

`/api/test/34` will work for `Get([FromUri] int id){}`

`/api/test/` will work for `Get() {}`